# using the dots argument in replicate expression fails - why exactly?

Tags: r, function, evaluation

I want to use the dots arguments (`...`) in an expression in `replicate`. I noticed that they do not have an effect doing it this way:

```
foo <- function(k=1, n=10, ...) 
{
  replicate(k, rnorm(n, ...))
}

foo(2, mean=100)
```

Results do not have a mean of 100.

```
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.2859647 -0.1046510
[2,] -0.7867414  0.5347617
```

Using a wrapper, however, will work.

```
foo2 <- function(k=1, n=10, ...) 
{
  f <- function() rnorm(n, ...)
  replicate(k, f())
}

foo2(2, mean=100)
```

Now, the results do have a mean of 100.

```
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 100.9644 100.6287
[2,] 100.0804 101.0218
```

**What exactly are the mechanics going on here during the evaluation of the `expr` argument in `replicate`. Can anyone give an explanation of the behaviour?**

Comment: you are right. thanks! And for me: RTM, RTM :/

Comment: The joys of non-standard evaluation. Just use `sapply` directly in this specific example.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is documented:

> If expr is a function call, be aware of assumptions about where it is
>   evaluated, and in particular what ... might refer to. You can pass
>   additional named arguments to a function call as additional named
>   arguments to replicate: see ‘Examples’.

And in the "Examples" section:

```
## use of replicate() with parameters:
foo <- function(x = 1, y = 2) c(x, y)
# does not work: bar <- function(n, ...) replicate(n, foo(...))
bar <- function(n, x) replicate(n, foo(x = x))
bar(5, x = 3)
```